# SimpleDateFormat - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, simpledateformat, illegalargumentexception

I seem to be getting an IllegalArgumentException when trying to process a Date object for database storage that's gained through passing new Date() in the constructor to spawn todays Date and time:

`Ingrediant newIngrediant = new Ingrediant(id, name, location, new Date(), price);
dbAdapter.insertIngrediant(newIngrediant);`

And where the problem is occurring is within my dbAdapter:

```
    ContentValues newIngrediantValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newIngrediantValues.put(KEY_ID, _ingrediant.getIngrediantId());
    newIngrediantValues.put(KEY_INGREDIANT_NAME, _ingrediant.getIngrediantName());
    newIngrediantValues.put(KEY_INGREDIANT_LOCATION, _ingrediant.getIngrediantLocation());
    Log.d("log", "---DATE NOW PROCESSING---");
    //Convert date to long (db stores date as long)
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YY hh:mm");
        Log.d("log", "1");
        String dateString = df.format(_ingrediant.getDateFound());
        Log.d("log", "2");
        Date date = df.parse(dateString);
        Log.d("log", "3");
        long dateLong = date.getTime();
        Log.d("log", "4");
        newIngrediantValues.put(KEY_DATE_FOUND, dateLong); //Long
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

Having looked at the Debugger, it has picked up todays date but when it comes to the formatting pattern it has no value registered therefore I think its something to do with that. The database itself stores the date as a long which is why later I was required to convert it before adding it in. Any ideas on whats happening? Thanks much

Comment: What is the type of the value returned by `_ingrediant.getDateFound()`? `format()` only `java.util.Date` objects, converting to and from string is redundant.

Comment: @laalto getDateFound() returns a Date value. I'm only converting the Date passed to a string so I can then format the date using SimpleDateFormat, then its required to be converted into a long for storage.

Comment: Why not use `getDateFound().getTime()` instead then to get the long value... However, at least post the full exception to get better help with it.

Comment: @laalto having had another look at the variables in Debug mode, a `com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.` Exception occurred, with this identified within LogCat `04-23 10:28:53.331: D/dalvikvm(1365):   JDWP invocation returning with exceptObj=0x4175f8c0 (Ljava/lang/NullPointerException;)`

Comment: @laalto Seemed to have fixed it now, it was indeed to do with the pattern since it was returning null in the debugger meaning it wasn't accepted, replaced it with the full version using 

`EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss` then gradually reduced it down to what I was looking for which is:
`dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm` and it was accepted which is quite unusual. Thanks for your help.